# Return to previous tab when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using the following structure to organize my screens

There is a bottom tab navigator to show two screens: `Jobs` and `Notification`. `Jobs` screen is a stack navigator that has two screens: `Job` for a list of jobs and `JobDetail` for displaying the detail of a job. When clicked on a notification I need to navigate to the respective `JobDetail` screen.

My question is: is there a way to return back to the `Notification` tab by pressing the back button from the `JobDetail` screen, given that I navigated to the `JobDetail` screen by clicking on one of the notifications in the first place? Currently, when I click the back button on the `JobDetail` screen it takes me back to the `Job` screen and instead I want it to go back to the `Notification` screen.

I've also included a working demo here: https://snack.expo.dev/@atosh502/go-back-to-tab-example

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74872397/tab-navigators-goback-not-working-properly-on-react-native-navigation), you have to add `backBehavior` prop to the tab navigator.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  ...
  backBehavior={'history'}
>
  // ...
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Check out the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#backbehavior) for more.

---

Old answer:

This seems to be an issue with `@react-navigation/native: ^6.x` going back to version 5.x may solve the issue. Just use

```
npm install @react-navigation/native@5.9.8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes made and hope it'll work for you too:

```
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Job"
        component={Job} //remove JobStack and keep just Job screen
        />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notification"
        component={NotificationStack} //keep NotificationStack instead of page so you'll get back to that page
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
// remove/comment your JobStack screen    
// const JobStack = () => {
//   return (
//     <Stack.Navigator>
//       <Stack.Screen name="Job" component={Job} />
//       <Stack.Screen name="JobDetail" component={JobDetail} />
//     </Stack.Navigator>
//   )
// }

//Add this NotificationStack screen
const NotificationStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Jobs" component={JobDetail} options={{title: 'Notification'}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Please check this working demo here: [click here](https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/go-back-to-tab-example)

Comment: ok that works... I forgot to mention in the question that I also need to go to the details page from the list of jobs... but thanks for the answer I think I have to include the details screen in both the Job stack as well as the notification stack.... I was hoping there was any other way to do it