# Tab Navigator's `goBack` not working properly on React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I created a tab navigator for an app using `@react-navigation/native: ^6.0.16`. But when I tried to go back it always goes back to the first screen on the tab navigator.
For example if I navigate from Home >> Notifications >> Profile and press the android back button instead of Notifications I reach Home. Basically going back on any tab (other than Home) navigates me back to home.
This issue does not seem to be a problem for `@react-navigation/native: v5.x` but I rather not go back to using version 5.x.
Is there any way I can fix this issue on version 6.x?

You can checkout a small snack of the issue [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@manil_softnep_malla/f8dc7d).
Just goto *package.json* and replace `"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",` with `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",` to get the intended output.

Comment: where exactly are you navigating in your provided snack? you have only added the mentioned tabs

Comment: @DavidScholz I am using the android back button to goBack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#backbehavior) here, you can specify the behaviour you want:

> This controls what happens when goBack is called in the navigator.
> This includes pressing the device's back button or back gesture on
> Android.
>
> It supports the following values:
>
> firstRoute - return to the first screen defined in the navigator
> (default) initialRoute - return to initial screen passed in
> initialRouteName prop, if not passed, defaults to the first screen
> order - return to screen defined before the focused screen history -
> return to last visited screen in the navigator; if the same screen is
> visited multiple times, the older entries are dropped from the history
> none - do not handle back button